# Adding new child-Node to specific parent-Node

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add a new child node into specific parent node.

The thing is that I can't find a property I could use to specify which parent Node I want to use.
Only I can use is:

```
 TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode)
```

But I don't want to use `SelectedNode`.

What I need should look like this:

```
TreeView1.ParentNode(Me.ds_Tables.Table.Rows(a).Item(0)).Nodes.Add(newNode)
```

**edit:**
So, I wrote ParentNode just to make it clear that that's a node where I will add a new node to.
Relationship between nodes and datatable is that I am using table column result to give a name to Node.

The thing is that my table looks like (`id, code, name, parentId`) `parentId` is the id column from that table. So, when parentId is filled (not `Null`) that means that that result is a part of another result from that table. (I hope that's clear for you, if it's not I'll try to explain in different way).

So, basically I have to find all results who has `parentId` filled and find which result own it and put that name into that "parent Node".

Comment: You can traverse all nodes of `TreeView1` and search for the right one. To know which the right on is, you can use the `Tag` property of a `TreeNode` object, which can hold arbitrary data.

Comment: @WeSt yeah I thought I could use Tags, but that seems like a double job, for nothing, which is something I am already doing. I am just looking for a way to do it in one or two lines of code, which is, I hope, possible.

Comment: then you will need to tell us a little bit more of the relation between the table rows and nodes and what you mean when saying `ParentNode(...)`.

Comment: @WeSt I just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1

It seems you read all the data at once at some point and then construct the tree. If that is the case, you can construct the TreeNodes fully before adding them to the TreeView:

```
Dim items As New List(Of Item)()
Dim map As New Dictionary(Of Integer, TreeNode)()

' first, create all TreeNode objects
For Each item As var In items
    Dim node As New TreeNode()
    ' set node values
    map.Add(item.Id, node)
Next

' second, construct the relations
For Each item As var In items
    Dim node = map(item.Id)
    If item.ParendID.HasValue Then
        map(item.ParentID).Nodes.Add(node)
    Else ' no parent = root node
        TreeView.Nodes.Add(node)
    End If
Next
```

## Option 2

If your tree is dynamic, you can still keep a global dictionary indicating which `Id` links to which `TreeNode`:

```
Private map As New Dictionary(Of Integer, TreeNode)();
```

## Option 3

Use the `Tag` property and write an Extension Method for `TreeNodeCollection`:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function Find(nodes As TreeNodeCollection, item As Object) As TreeNode
    For Each node As var In nodes
        If node.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso node.Tag.Equals(item) Then
            Return node
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing ' or throw an exception
End Function
```

and then use

```
TreeView.Nodes.Find(parentID).AddNodes(...)
```

Comment: I hate that I have to write this, but I posted my question with vb.net tag :)

Comment: @Hoh haha oh yeah, sorry ^^ One sec :)

Comment: Yes, this helped. Thanks a lot and sorry for late respond ;)